# How to create an Uri to google that doesn't escape characteres

Tags: c#, google-maps, uri

I have a call to google maps WS using signed URLs.
An example: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=-22.7595196841997,-47.1268794922774&destination=-29.0062986,-49.7737413&mode=driving&waypoints=-27.2050171,-49.6415186|-27.2496772,-49.9392315|-28.0071174,-49.5894682|&sensor=false&client=gme-myClient&signature=QmH-MYSignature

But when a I call: 
**_HttpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);**
It automatically escape Uri to: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=-22.7595196841997,-47.1268794922774&destination=-29.0062986,-49.7737413&mode=driving&waypoints=-27.2050171,-49.6415186%7C-27.2496772,-49.9392315%7C-28.0071174,-49.5894682%7C&sensor=false&client=gme-myClient&signature=QmH-P2kPs4Qt9wiQK4G0f6tH2ck=

I'm using now:
**_HttpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(this.url, true));**

It works like a charm, but its obsolete so I need how to do that without beeing obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the string literal for the uri, you can place an @ sign in front of it like this:

```
string x = @"\\\\"
```

To get a string of four characters.